# Send a file over XMODEM with payload size = 64

Tags: serial-port

I am trying to communicate with a microcontroller over the ancient (but simple) [XMODEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMODEM) protocol. The two ways that I have found of sending a file are through `minicom` (interactive) and through `cx` (non-interactive). However, payload size cannot be specified (defaults to 128 bytes), while the chip is expecting 64 bytes.

Is there a way, using commands from Ubuntu repos, makefiles or even bash scripts, to send *non-interactively* a file over XMODEM with payload of 64 bytes? Also, short checksum(1 byte) must be supported.

Comment: is xmodem the only protocol available?  any chance of, say, zmodem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code for a good free-software xmodem implementation is available in the `lrzsz` package.  You could hack the source and build your own custom version of `sx` with 64-byte packets.

https://ohse.de/uwe/software/lrzsz.html

Note, however, that xmodem was designed for 128 byte packets (i don't recall ever hearing of an implementation with smaller packet sizes) because files were **always** a multiple of 128 bytes in size on CP/M back in 1977.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMODEM

Comment: Indeed, after I went to bed I realized that the 128 bytes are a constant in the standard. On another note, how do I use lrzsz? `lrzsz is already the newest version.` but `lrzsz: command not found`.

Comment: `lrzsz` is the name of the entire software package.  It includes `sz`, and `sx` commands for sending via zmodem and xmodem.  and `rz`, `rx` for receiving.  See `man sx` for more details.

Comment: I changed the payload length at the receiver and am now receiving files successfully. However, I [can't seem to set the baudrate of sx](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239425/send-a-file-over-serial-port-with-xmodem-protocol).